# How can I include a predicate along with Included properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Currently I have a function that allows me to query the database while including some other related tables in the results to prevent a return hit to the database that I know would occur otherwise if I don't:

```
public class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IEntityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    private readonly DbContext dc;

    public EntityRepository()
    {
        dc = new DbContext(Utility.Config.GetEntityDbConnection());
        dbSet = dc.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
            foreach (var includedProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                dbSet.Include(includedProperty).Load();
            }

            return dbSet;
    }
}
```

However, I need to be able to also use a where clause prior to the include so that it doesn't try to query the entire database when it fires the `Load()` method.

I was trying to do something like this (which obviously doesn't work because you can reassign `dbset` like in my sample code below).

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchForIncluding(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
           dbset = dbSet.Where(predicate);  //THIS DOESN'T WORK OBVIOUSLY

           foreach (var includedProperty in includeProperties)
           {
                dbSet.Include(includedProperty).Load();
           }
    }
```

Comment: is the type of `dbSet`? is it an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`?

Comment: Oops - sorry.  Updating!

Comment: so the class containing all this code is something like `MyClass<TEntity>` i presume?

Comment: what is the actual error you're getting on that line?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>` to `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: oh, yeah, duh, you don't want to try to reassign the dbset, you want to store it as something else, like `var myREsult = dbSet.Where(predicate)`. but as dasblinkenlight says you should apply the includes before the where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) library. Download the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) and and use the `AsExpandable` extension method:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchForIncluding(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            query = query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
        }
        return query;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Just adding the where clause before `Load()` as in dasblinkenlight's example didn't work.  You have to also have the where again on the main query so your example worked perfectly.

Comment: happy for you my friend, Also I recommend you take a look to this project: https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to apply the predicate in a call to `Where` between `Include` and `Load`, like this:

```
foreach (var includedProperty in includeProperties)
{
     dbSet.Include(includedProperty).Where(predicate).Load();
}
```

Comment: I thought of that. I was concerned about putting it on each call in the loop but that's probably fine, right?  I was thinking that I needed it prior to the include loop but if I put on include in the loop, that's the same thing - basically?

Comment: @RichC `Where` clause is applied on the DB side anyway, so it does not cost you much to add a `Where` in the loop, even though the predicate is the same all the time.

Comment: ok - giving this a shot right now and I'll report back my findings soon.  thanks!