# Repository generic method GetById using eager loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I am using Entity Framework and would like to create generic **GetById** method in Repository class with eager loading:

Here is my method which uses lazy-loading:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
  {
    return DbSet.Find(id);
  }
```

I know method **Find** does not support eager loading, but how it is possible to modify this method to use eager loading, so that I use this method as follows(for an example):

```
_unitOfWork.MyRepository.GetById(includeProperties: "Users");
```

Comment: Try this question [include-a-predicate-along-with-included-properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112285/how-can-i-include-a-predicate-along-with-included-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to use `FirstOrDefault` with predicate over the `DbSet` with `Include`s. It's not hard to build manually a predicate using [`Expression.Equal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but the main challenge is how to get the key property name. Luckily we can use some `ObjectContext` methods to do that, so the implementation could be like this (assuming we have access to the concrete `DbContext` instance):

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(object id, params string[] includeProperties)
{
    var propertyName = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext
        .CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Single().Name;

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName),
            Expression.Constant(id)),
        parameter);

    var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();
    if (includeProperties != null && includeProperties.Length > 0)
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include);
    return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Comment: here i am getting an error: var propertyName = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext
                .CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Single().Name;
"unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Model.ProductDetail]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'."

Comment: @PranavMishra The procedure is expecting the `Context` variable to be of  `DbContext` (or derived) class type. While the error you are getting indicates a variable of type `DbSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the update for Entity Framework Core 2.0. Also this method using the new metadata properties with EF to automatically get the first level navigation properties.

```
public virtual T Get(object id)
{
        var propertyName = "AddressId";

        //get all navigation properties defined for entity
        var navigationProps = _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations();

        //turn those navigation properties into a string array
        var includeProperties = navigationProps.Select(p => p.PropertyInfo.Name).ToArray();

        //make parameter of type T
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        //create the lambda expression
        var predicateLeft = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
        var predicateRight = Expression.Constant(id);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(predicateLeft, predicateRight), parameter);

        //get queryable
        var query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

        //apply Include method to the query multiple times
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include);

        //return first item in query
        return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This In Repository

```
public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
    }
```

and This In Action Method

```
var User =  _IRepositoryWrapper.User.FindByCondition(x=>x.Id == id).Include(a=>a.Photos).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: They want to return `TEntity`.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the question posed, which is how to invoke eager loading.